# Spring 3 @Controller is not being invoked for Get request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am attempting to use Spring 3' MVC support for annotated controllers in my web application.

In my application-context.xml, I've added the following:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.def.etc"/>
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>
```

My Controller is annotated as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/optimizerRules")
public class OptimizerRulesController {
private OptimizerRulesService optimizerRulesService;
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(OptimizerRulesController.class);

public OptimizerRulesController()
{
    LOG.info("Initializing OptimizerRulesController");
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getRuleAttributesAndRules(ModelMap model)
{
    LOG.info("Entering getRuleAttributesAndRules method");
    }
```

When I start up my application I can see in my logs that the OptimizerRulesController has been initialized. I can also see the following:

```
Creating instance of bean 'optimizerRulesController'
Initializing OptimizerRulesController
Mapped URL path [/optimizerRules] onto handler 'optimizerRulesController'
```

However, when I invoke my application using http://localhost:8080/appName/optimizerRules I get a 404 error!
What configuration am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a view page for it? Or a return value?

Comment: Can you put dispatcher configuration in web.xml, please?

Comment: @DaveNewton - yes, I do have it below, I just shortened it above for brevity, but regardless I should still see an entry for that log.

Comment: @Sinuhe - will do later, when I have access again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC would normally log that no mapping is found for a particular request at WARN level. Assuming you're not seeing that in your logs and assuming that WARN is enabled, and since you're not seeing your own log statement, it sounds like your request isn't even hitting the Spring MVC DispatcherServlet, which probably means the URL is wrong.

The URL should be http://server:port/war/dispatcherServletMapping/optimizerRules, so your web.xml should tell you the missing path component, if my assumptions are valid.

Comment: Thanks, this resolved it. My web.xml's DispatcherServlet was just matching against a *.htm URL path. Once I changed my URL to opimizerRules.htm it worked!